# Keycloak Quarkus, I don't see the base or its tables

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using bitnami's Keycloak v.20.0.0 (Quarkus) image with docker-compose. Everything works fine and I have no problems with any configuration, however when I want to see the tables in the PostgreSQL database, I access without problems but I don't see anything! I don't see that any table or database exists.
I understand that I have to start Keycloak in dev mode which I configured but I still don't see anything.
What am I doing wrong?

this is my setup:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  keycloak:        
    image: bitnami/keycloak:20.0.1
    container_name: keycloak_20
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres          
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS: "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled"
      KC_HOSTNAME: postgres
      ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/export:/tmp/export
      - ./rus-theme:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/themes/my-theme
      - ./keycloak/configuration/standalone-ha.xml:/bitnami/keycloak/configuration/standalone-ha.xml:ro
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
        /opt/bitnami/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev

    depends_on:
      - postgres
    
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  
  mailhog:
    # Conectarse al nombre del container para acceder
    # Ejemplo: mailhog:1025
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    logging:
      driver: 'none'  # disable saving logs
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui
  
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

[image: PostgreSQL Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_*` properties were used in the old versions of Keycloak (pre-Quarkus).
New properties are defined as `KC_DB_*` (see https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=db)